# How to add a CircleAvatar to a Flutter TextField?

Tags: flutter

Trying to create a post screen, where the user can select an image and post a text.
The main problem that I have is that I need to add a Cirlce avatar for the user on the left side of the textField and a hint "Insert your text here"

this is what I achieved so far:

```
class CityRecommendations extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
        child: DropdownAppBar(),
      ),
      body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Insert your message",
              ),
              scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
            MessageBox(),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

How to add a circleAvatar for the user?

Answer (score 2):

I do not sure this is you wanted

```
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.person)),
          Expanded(
              child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Insert your message",
              ),
              scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ))
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can use [CircleAvatar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) widget for that.

> A circle that represents a user.

> Typically used with a user's profile image, or, in the absence of such an image, the user's initials. A given user's initials should always be paired with the same background color, for consistency.

> If foregroundImage fails then backgroundImage is used. If backgroundImage fails too, backgroundColor is used.

> The onBackgroundImageError parameter must be null if the backgroundImage is null. The onForegroundImageError parameter must be null if the foregroundImage is null.

Answer (score -4):

You can wrap your TextField with CircleAvater
[image]